# python subprocess call makefile

Tags: python, makefile, subprocess

I want to use a python (2.6) script to build a target in a makefile. The makefile $shell command doesn't seem to work when make runs.

build.py:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["gmake","libs"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1)
p1.wait()
output = p1.returncode
print ("gmake returned with return code " + str (output))
```

makefile:

```
BUILD_OPSYS := $shell uname)

ifeq ($(BUILD_OPSYS), Linux)
    DATETIME:= date
else
    DATETIME:=/mksnt/date.exe
endif

libs:
    @printf "***Start building $@ libraries at "
    $(DATETIME)
```

Results in the following output:

```
***Start building libs libraries at gmake: /mksnt/date.exe: Command not found
gmake: *** [libs] Error 127
gmake returned with return code 2
```

Comment: It seems more a `Makefile` question than a Python question. What happens if you run: `["gmake", "BUILD_OS=linux", "libs"]`?

Comment: When I manually run the makefile with the BUILD__OS environment variable set, then the makefile is able to run the correct version of date. It seems more like the environment variables set in python are not being passed to the gmake execution.

Comment: How many underscores in the name? Btw, It is not what I've asked. I meant that you put the command into `Popen()` (Python syntax for a list hints at that). Also, it shouldn't matter but you could pass `env=dict(os.environ, BUILD_OS="linux")` parameter to `Popen()` instead of modifying `os.environ` inplace.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for another way. This is the simple test. I have fifty to a hundred environmental settings that would make this construct unworkable. I'm trying to understand whether Popen inherits the os.environment settings. I thought it did. Maybe it's something wrong with shell=False default setting?

Comment: (1) yes, a child process does inherit environment variables from the parent (2) to understand why the test fails in your case, (for debugging) run the commands I've suggested and report the results (update you question): it may help others to help you

Comment: Thanks for the help J.F., and for sticking with me.  I think you are correct, I am having a makefile problem.  I will consider this closed, and "may" reopen a makefile question.

Comment: Rewrote question based on comments from J.F. Sebastian.

Comment: I don't see anything in the edits that is related to my comments

Comment: How do you run our Python script and how to you run your make by hand? Exact commands are missing from the question.